# Mysterious string encoding with json.dumps on windows with python 3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, encoding

We are discovering different behaviour of `json.dumps` on Linux and Windows

```
jsonData = json.load(open('test.json'))
print(jsonData)

jsonStr = json.dumps(jsonData, ensure_ascii=False)
print(jsonStr)
```

Output on Linux: (python3.3)

```
{'name': 'Müller'}
{"name": "Müller"}
```

Output on Windows: (python3.4)

```
{'name': 'Müller'}
{"name": "M\xc3\xbcller"}
```

Are we missing something? `test.json` looks like `{'name': 'Müller'}`.

How is it possible to read UTF-8 Files with Python 3 on Windows?

Comment: And what encoding did you use to *write* the file on Windows?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue on Mac on Python 3.4, certainly; the output produced looks like UTF-8 data was interpreted as Latin-1.  Are you **100% certain** that the JSON data was not read from a file?

Comment: Sorry, I experimented a lot and put the wrong code up.

Comment: @Nicolas I've edited the question to what I understand you to be asking. Please confirm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't rely on the default encoding when opening files; your JSON file is encoded to UTF-8 but you are opening it with a single-byte codec instead (probably CP1252, the Windows Latin-1 codepage):

```
jsonData = json.load(open('test.json', encoding='utf8'))
```

From the [`open()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> The default encoding is **platform dependent** (whatever `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns)

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the missing part.